# Laravel 5: Change array passed via $request

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, request

I have this statement:

```php
$request->lines[$i]['price_ex_vat'] = preg_replace("/([^0-9\\.])/i", "",  $request->lines[$i]['price_ex_vat']);
```

Its purpose is to remove the currency formatting on a value but I get the error `Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$lines has no effect`

Googling tells me I need to use ->merge() but it is just not sinking in how to do that. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laravel uses Symfony's ParameterBag to store the request's data it internally does this:

```
$p = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag(['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux']);
$p->add(['baz' => 'xyz']);

dump(
    $p->all()
);
```

Which prints out:

```
array:2 [
  "foo" => "bar"
  "baz" => "xyz"
]
```

Laravel's request exposes `merge` method that calls `ParameterBag`'s add method internally. All is good until you manipulate one dimension data.

In your case, the solution **could be** like this:

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('/', 'POST', 
    [
        'lines' => [
            ['price_ex_vat' => 'foo'],
            ['price_ex_vat' => 'bar'],
            ['price_ex_vat' => 'baz'],
        ],
    ]
);

$data = $request->input();
$data['lines'][1]['price_ex_vat'] = 'xyz'; // preg_replace or whatever you want.

dd(
    $request->merge($data)->input();
);
```

Which prints accordingly:

```
array:1 [
  "lines" => array:3 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "price_ex_vat" => "foo"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "price_ex_vat" => "xyz"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      "price_ex_vat" => "baz"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `$request->lines` is an **array** you are iterating through and want to change `price_ex_vat` on it. I would suggest making a separate variable to do the changes on it, then use **merge** to replace `$request->lines`

```php
$arr = $request->lines;
foreach($arr as $line){ //or you can use a normal for loop if you prefer
 $line['price_ex_vat'] = preg_replace("/([^0-9\\.])/i", "",  $line['price_ex_vat']); //your changes here
}
$request->merge('lines',$arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error here though `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Http\Request::merge() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: The following worked for me: `$lineData = $request->input();` `$request->merge($lineData)->input();`